# How to get signature from Same Counter Party, multiple times in a single flow?

Tags: corda

I need to implement the scenario like, there are CentralParty,PartyA,PartyB.
CentralParty needs to initiate a flow where there will be 3 transactions in a loop ,where inititor is always Central party and the otherparty will be Party A 2 times.

i.e.I m trying to collecting signature from same counterparty with multiple times from a single flow by referring the below link

[Corda returning Multiple transactions in a single flow call ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797667/corda-returning-multiple-transactions-in-a-single-flow-call)

```
val flowSessionMap = mutableMapOf<Party, FlowSession>()
var ftx:MutableList<SignedTransaction> = mutableListOf<SignedTransaction>()
var signedTransaction:SignedTransaction

val fullySignedTransactions = matchingStateList.forEach { matchingState ->

    val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Matching(), matchingState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
    val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
            .addOutputState(matchingState, IOU_CONTRACT_ID)
            .addCommand(txCommand)

    // Stage 2.
    progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
    // Verify that the transaction is valid.
    txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

    // Stage 3.
    progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
    // Sign the transaction.
    val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, ourIdentity.owningKey)


    val sessions = (listOf(PartyA).map { signer ->
        flowSessionMap.getOrPut(signer) {
            initiateFlow(signer)
        }
    })

    val fullySignedTransaction = subFlow(CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow(
        partSignedTx, sessions)
    )

    signedTransaction = fullySignedTransaction

    ftx.add(signedTransaction)
}

for (transaction in ftx) {
    subFlow(FinalityFlow(transaction))
}
```

Responder flow is defined as follows:

```
 class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartyFlow) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                val output = stx.tx.outputs.single().data
                "This must be an Matching State transaction." using (output is MatchingState)
                val Match = output as MatchingState
                "I won't accept IOUs with a value over 100." using (iou.value <= 100)
            }
        }

        return subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
    }
}
```

Where CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow is defined as follows:

```
 @InitiatingFlow
class CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow(val signedTransaction: SignedTransaction, val sessions: List<FlowSession>): FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        return subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTransaction, sessions))
    }
}
```

And the responder for CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow is defined as follows:

```
    @InitiatedBy(CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow::class)
class CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlowResponder(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartyFlow) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {
                TODO("Check the transaction here.")
            }
        }

        return subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
    }
}
```

While running the same code I got an error like

```
[WARN ] 15:43:18,817 [Node thread-1] (FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:111) flow.[82900238-9223-4ace-ba78-9ecc45121b11].run - Terminated by unexpected exception {}
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counterparty flow on O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB has completed without sending data
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.confirmNoError(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:488) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.waitForMessage(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:444) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendAndReceiveInternal(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:385) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:203) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:29) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:40) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.sendPayloadAndReceiveDataRequest(SendTransactionFlow.kt:70) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:48) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:31) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignatureFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:142) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignatureFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:135) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:114) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:64) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at com.example.flow.ExampleFlowMatching$CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow.call(ExampleFlowMatching.kt:260) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.example.flow.ExampleFlowMatching$CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow.call(ExampleFlowMatching.kt:258) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at com.example.flow.ExampleFlowMatching$ExampleFlowMatchingInitiator.call(ExampleFlowMatching.kt:202) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.example.flow.ExampleFlowMatching$ExampleFlowMatchingInitiator.call(ExampleFlowMatching.kt:45) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
```

Comment: Can you add the responder flow as well please?

Comment: Responder flow is added and I have added CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow as well.@joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are initiating the flow sessions in your main flow, `ExampleFlowMatchingInitiator`, instead of inside `CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow`.

When you call `initiateFlow`, it starts a flow session with the counterparty in the context of the current `InitiatingFlow`. So when you call `initiateFlow` in `ExampleFlowMatchingInitiator`, the counterparty will check whether it has any responders registered for `ExampleFlowMatchingInitiator`. It does - `Acceptor` - so it starts a flow session to speak to the counterparty using `Acceptor`.

If you call `initiateFlow` inside `CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow` instead, the counterparty will check whether it has any responders registered for `CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlow`. It does - `CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlowResponder` - so it starts a flow session to speak to the counterparty using `CollectSignaturesInitiatingFlowResponder` instead.